# Error when Running Vicuna's FastChat Model without GPU

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gpt-4

I wish to use the Vicuna open source model to train my dataset.

I don't have a GPU in my computer, so I wanted to use their RESTful API Server. I used Windows PowerShell for the commands below.

According to their explanation (https://github.com/lm-sys/FastChat/blob/main/docs/openai_api.md)

First, I launched the command

```
> python3 -m fastchat.serve.controller
```

Then, it opened a localhost for me. I opened it in my browser and it displayed the following message:

```
> {"detail":"Not Found"}.
```

Next, I opened a new PowerShell window and ran their second command:

```
> python3 -m fastchat.serve.model_worker --model-path lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.3
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Does this error occur because I do not have a GPU in my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Just add "--device cpu" to your python3 command.